# What does the quotient space of a CW complex by a subcomplex mean?

Tags: general-topology

From [p.8 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch0.pdf#page=8&zoom=150,0,359):

> If $(X,A)$ is a CW pair consisting of a cell complex $X$ and a subcomplex $A$, then the quotient space $X/A$ inherits a natural cell complex structure from $X$.

It talks about a quotient space of $X/A$ where $A$ is a subcomplex of $X$.  What is the equivalence relation forming this quotient space?  Thanks.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an image in the gray space?

Comment: Somehow Zev Chonoles got that to work when he edited my other post.  I guess it's a moderator privelege to auto-generate a screenshot from a given link.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: I did not auto-generate any screenshot. Just take a screenshot as you would normally from your computer of the relevant piece of the document. Then upload it as a picture (which [any user with reputation of $\geq 10$ can do](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user)). By the way, [I'm not a moderator anymore](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9282/264).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $X$ is a topological space, and $A$ is a subspace, the notation $X/A$ refers to the space obtained by identifying all of $A$, ie, collapsing $A$ to a point.

Explicitly, the equivalence relation is $x\sim y$ if and only if $x,y\in A$.  Notice this leaves all points in $X\setminus A$ unidentified.  The topology of $X/A$ is just the quotient topology under $\sim$.

As an example, let $X=S^2$ and $A$ be an equator.  Then $X/A$ pinches the equator to a point, leaving the wedge product of two spheres.